# How to make mac not move windows for a couple seconds on wake

Tags: sleep-wake, window-manager

I have 2 external monitors I use with my MacbookPro in addition to the built in screen. Whenever I resume the mac from sleep, the 2 monitors take a few seconds to boot up. In that time, macos determines that no displays are connected and moves all the windows to the laptop display, ruining my layout. Can this be avoided? I've tried apps like Rectangle Pro to save layouts, but since I have multiple instances of each app rectangle manages to mangle the layout even more, taking 2 different windows of the same app and stacking them.

Answer (score 1):

What could be happening is the Mac is trying to get EDID from the problem monitor and timing out.  If there was some way to make the Mac skip this check and just override it with some specific settings that might resolve the issue.   Another trick would be to use an [EDID emulator](https://a.co/d/aLWEHNL) that plugs in line between your monitor and mac and answers the DDC queries coming from the Mac so your monitor can take its sweet time waking up.